# Convert bbox in meters (stereographic projection)

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

I need to convert the bbox H-SAF area [25-75°N lat, 25°W-45°E long] in meters in the stereographic projection (EPSG:3413 WGS 84 / NSIDC Polar Stereographic North). How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "convert"? Does that mean to find the projected coordinates of the four corners?  Or maybe to project all four sides of the bounding box (they will be rounded)?  Or perhaps something else?  And could you also elaborate on what you mean by "solve"?  Would that refer to a formula or to applying software--and if software, what program do you have in mind?

Comment: Most algorithms used in the EPSG registry are available in a [guidance note 7-2](http://www.epsg.org/Guidancenotes.aspx).

Comment: I want to find the projected coordinates of the four corners with gdal tools if possible or a formula.